# How to run the code for large variables

Tags: matlab

I have one code like below-

```
W = 3;
i = 4;
s = fullfact(ones(1,i)*(W + 1)) - 1;
p2 = unique(sort(s(sum(s,2) == i,:),2),'rows');
```

I can run this code only upto "i=11" but i want to run this code for upto "i=25".When i run these code for i=12 it shows error message "Out of Memory".
I need to keep these code as it is.How can i modify these code for larger value of "i"?

Matlab experts need your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Since you're taking only the unique rows that add to "i" anyway, you don't need the huge matrix created by fullfact.  You might want to have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9477/ .Why are you removing cases where the third column is larger than 1? - doesn't match with your comment.

Comment: I have edited my question.I saw the link that you have given but cannot understand how can i solve my problem? Can you please help me?

Comment: @nkjt-In the link (that u are provided to me) all the solution was done for Pynthon.But i am using Matlab so can you please help me to solve this "out of memory" problem using Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Just wanting to do silly things is not enough. You are generating arrays that are simply too large to fit into memory.

See that the size of the matrix s is a function of i here. size(s) will be 2^(2*i) by i. (By the way, some will argue it is a bad idea to use i as a variable, which is normally sqrt(-1), for such variables.)

So when i = 4, s is only 256x4.

When i = 11, s is 4194304x11. This array takes 369098752 bytes of space, so 370 megabytes.

When i = 25, the array will be of size

```
2^50*25
ans =
   2.8147e+16
```

Multiply that by 8 to get the memory needed. Something like 224 petabytes of memory! If you have that much memory, then send me a few terabytes of RAM. You won't miss them.

Comment: I agree with all of your comments that's why i want a good solution to solve this problem.

Comment: So the answer is to get a job with the NSA, or some other organization that does have hundreds of petabytes of RAM laying around (and will let you borrow them.) Sorry, but the ultimate answer is to recognize that computers have limits. Or ... completely reformulate your problem. But you are the one who insists on using exactly the code you have written.

Comment: Many many thanks for your valuable comment...Ok i am changing my words,dont need to keep my code as it is...Can you reformulate this code and run for i upto 25? If you can do so then i will be very helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are times when MATLAB runs out of memory. You can get the amount of memory available at any point of time by executing the following:

```
memory
```

However, I would suggest follow one of the strategies to reduce memory usage available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/memory.html). Also, you might want to clear the variables which are not required in every iteration by

```
clear variable_name
```

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand your point.Before run the code every time i write clear all to in command window but it shows the same error message.

Comment: You should try this:W = 3;
i = 4;
s = fullfact(ones(1,i)*(W + 1)) - 1;
p2 = unique(sort(s(sum(s,2) == i,:),2),'rows'); clear s
condition=p2(:,3)>1; %Only find the combination those starts from 1
p2(condition,:)=[]; This might not be solving your problem. Could you paste the output of memory command.

Comment: Still getting the same error. The error message is below:??? Error using ==> zeros
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> fullfact at 34
design = zeros(ssize,cols,class(levels));

Error in ==> com_all at 21
s = fullfact(ones(1,i)*(W + 1)) -1 ;